# MvvmCross MvxApplication class overriding for different platforms. (Plus, encryption)

Tags: encryption, touch, urlencode, mvvmcross

I've got *two questions* here. The first one is just *specific* and another one is more *general*, but is a source of the first one.

So, my specific problem: I want **to use Encryption** (actually, Hashing) algorithms with using **System.Security.Cryptography** namespace (for instance, SHA256Managed class).

I found out that (happily) Xamarin has implemented those in [System.dll](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/assemblies).
But **it is not portable** and obviously can not be used from **Core application** directly.

But I've also found another great project -- [PclContrib](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/) -- which **allows** you to do that. But, unfortunately, they don't have the implementation for Touch and Android. (However, that still works great for Desktop (Web) and Windows Phone, plus, still can be included into Core (as it uses portable project)).

Anyway, to solve that **nicely**, I've decided to create some **base class** for the encryption methods and then override core methods which require the custom dll (for any custom system).

The way I did it (at least, trying to do) was:

Defining **virtual method** in **Core App** base class:

```
public virtual IEncryptionProvider CreateEncryptionProvider()
```

**Overriding Core App class** in **Touch project** with overriding CreateEncryptionProvider (which creates an instance of TouchEncryptionProvider class instance).

Core:

```
public class App : MvxApplication
```

Touch:

```
public class AppTouch : App
```

Launching it in *Touch setup.cs*:

```
protected override Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxApplication CreateApp (
{
    return new AppTouch();
}
```

But, that ***does not work*** for me. On startup I've got this exception message in log:
*"**Exception masked KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for** Mynamespace.Etc.LoginViewModel"*, which **works fine when I do new App() instead**. I am not sure if that message shows actual problem (as before it was saying the same even that was a problem with some third-party dll, unrelated to views at all). But speaking shortly, that's **just a primitive inheritance of App : MvxApplication**, but **placed** not **in** Core but **Touch project**.

So, does it requeire some more custom initialization for such situations or do I miss something else?

---

And, actually, more general question is how should I build such **Multiplatform approaches**? Actually, now I've got similar problem with HttpUtility.UrlEncode, which I would want to use in my Core project.

---

What is the MvvmCross "philosophy" to handle such situations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 'viewmodel not found' problem, this is caused because mvvmcross by default only looks for viewmodels in the Assembly containing your app.

If you want it to look in other assemblies, override ViewModelAssemblies in Setup.cs - see how this done in, for example, [MvvmCross - structuring shared View Models and Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199625/mvvmcross-structuring-shared-view-models-and-views/17200358#17200358)

---

For general multplatform approach, please read questions and answers like:

- [Platform-specific IoC in MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337063/platform-specific-ioc-in-mvvmcross?rq=1)
- [Instantiation of ViewModels and Service classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967454/instantiation-of-viewmodels-and-service-classes/16980207#16980207)

Please also remember you don't have to use PCLs - if you prefer to use file-linking between multiple platform-specific core projects, then you can of course use this approach.

---

Finally, please also try to ask one question per question - I find it makes stackoverflow work better for users and with search engines too. If you need to link questions, then you can just add a hyperlink reference - stackoverflow then marks them as related.

Comment: Well, that was not really a point to ask different questions right in on place, but mostly to illustrate the problem.
But, still, I do not completely catch your sentense about PCLs: "Please also remember you don't have to use PCLs - if you prefer to...". Because: a) PclContrib (with Encryption) is a "half-finished" thing, as it's really convenient to use as portable, but still it lacks Touch with Android, so I have to creat something in between (so, I have no choice). b) I do want to use PCLs, but a little bit lost in this stuff!